# 'deque iterator not dereferencable` while doing std::deque->front()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, visual-studio-2013, queue

following piece of code causes an assert "deque iterator not dereferencable" followed by an exception:

```
if (data[n].stateFlagQueue->empty()) cstate=0;
else
{
   cstate=data[n].stateFlagQueue->front();
   if (data[n].stateFlagQueue->size()>1) data[n].stateFlagQueue->pop();
}
```

The assert happens with data[n].stateFlagQueue->front() while stateflagQueue has a size of 3, so there are enough data available. The whole code shown above is secured by a mutex, same is true for the code that runs in an own thread and fills stateFlagQueue with data:

```
if ((data->stateFlagQueue->empty()) || 
    (data->stateFlagQueue->back()!=data->m_response.cstate))
 data->stateFlagQueue->push(data->m_response.cstate);
```

So...how can it happen this exception still occurs?

Thanks!

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Its the *same mutex* for both blocks, right ? You know, the one important enough to mention but apparently not to show us.

Comment: WhozCraig: yes it is the same mutex. The lock/unlock function is placed exactly around the code snippeds I posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved, there came a wrong mutex-unlock in between which caused this problem.